# How can I order by a particular element when loading XML via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have code like this to load the contents of an XML file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "SITESETUP_000003.XML",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (siteSetupRedemptionsRec) {
        var sitesetup = "<table><thead><th>REDEMPTIONS Redemption ID</th><th>REDEMPTIONS Name</th><th>REDEMPTIONS Item Id</th><th>REDEMPTIONS Amount</th><th>REDEMPTIONS Department</th><th>REDEMPTIONS Subdepartment</th></thead>";
        $(siteSetupRedemptionsRec).find('Redemptions').each(function () {
            var redemptionId = $(this).find('RedemptionID').text();
            var name = $(this).find('Name').text();
            var itemId = $(this).find('ItemID').text();
            var amount = $(this).find('Amount').text();
            var dept = $(this).find('Department').text();
            var subDept = $(this).find('Subdepartment').text();
            sitesetup += "<tr>";
            sitesetup += "<td>" + redemptionId + "</td>";
            sitesetup += "<td>" + name + "</td>";
            sitesetup += "<td>" + itemId + "</td>";
            sitesetup += "<td>" + amount + "</td>";
            sitesetup += "<td>" + dept + "</td>";
            sitesetup += "<td>" + subDept + "</td>";
            sitesetup += "</tr>";
        });
        sitesetup += "</table>";
        $('#Site_Setup3').append(sitesetup);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

How can I sort/order by a particular element or column? Such as by Name?

Comment: I would try using the undocumented .sort method first, though i've never used it on an xml doc.

Comment: You can use this excellent jQuery plugin : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/